# $|t|^p$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have been asked to prove in one exercise before this that if the second derivative of the function is non-negative, then the function is convex. Here is the solution of this below:[image]

One thing I don't understand is why don't we stop at the fact that the second derivative of this function is non negative. Why do they continue to check the convexity inequality. Isn't showing that the derivative is positive sufficient for proving convexity?

Second thing I don't understand, is why do we check for $x<0$ and $y>0$. Why not $x>0$  and $y>0$ or some other variation? Why does it matter for $x$ and $y$ to take any specific signs?

Comment: The function is not twice differentiable at $t=0$ (at least not for all $p$), so you can't reason about convexity on all of the real line "in one go".

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek what do you mean? The second derivative is then $0$ which satisfies the condition $f''(x)\geq 0 \Rightarrow f$ is convex

Comment: Consider $p=3/2$.